# .sendKeys method problems in WebDriver Sampler JMeter

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter

I'm making WebDriver Selenium scripts and trying to run them with JMeter.
I have an issue I don't understand. My code will crash at line 17 with this error in JMeter:

```
ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: 
import org.openqa.selenium.*; import java.time.Duration;   WDS.sampleResult.samp . . . '' : Error in method invocation: Method sendKeys( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement' : at Line: 17 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import java.time.Duration;   WDS.sampleResult.samp . . . '' : .sendKeys ( "value" ) 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import java.time.Duration;   WDS.sampleResult.samp . . . '' at line number 17
```

This is my code in WebDriver Sampler in JMeter:

[code with .sendKeys method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33afY.png)

What is the problem? Am I just blind?

I tried to import `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement` directly to the script and I also tried to change syntax because I learned it was necessary to put an Array instead of a String behind .sendKeys method, but it didn't work for me.

I am using apache-jmeter-5.5 and Script Language in WebDriver Sampler is set to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just violating [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), using [Beanshell is not recommended since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

The reason is that [WebElement.sendKeys()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#sendKeys(java.lang.CharSequence...)) function expects a [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) and you're trying to pass a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) there and Beanshell interpreter doesn't like it.

Switch the language to `groovy` and the issue will go away. See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: Choosing "groovy" solves the problem. Another solution is to edit code like this: e.g. `element.sendKeys(new String[]{"textToBeSent"});` instead of `element.sendKeys("textToBeSent");`